# почему не задается z index?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Не задается `z-index`.

```css
block {
  height: 440px;
  width: 270px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px #000000;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding: 40px 10px 0px 10px;
  position: relative;
}


/* .block::after{
    content: "";
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #016abb;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0px -10px -10px -10px;
} */

.foto-redonda {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.block::before {
  content: "";
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #016abb;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0px -10px -10px -10px;
}

.foto {
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="foto">
    <img class="foto-redonda" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=Foto" alt="Foto participante">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <h3>un señor cualquiera</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="text2">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc efficitur tellus vel sapien porta, eget bibendum libero viverra. Nullam turpis libero, viverra non lectus et, elementum mattis turpis. Sed laoreet, orci sed dignissim suscipit, orci sem
      ultrices turpis, interdum mollis nunc augue congue purus. Praesent a facilisis enim. Proin ultricies aliquet sem at suscipit. Nam mollis ipsum nec porttitor luctus. Sed non ex vitae odio vehicula efficitur eget at sapien. Curabitur nec pretium mauris.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Z-INDEX - не будет работать, если у элемента не  `position: absolute; position: fixed; position: relative;`

Comment: так а почему он на фотку не работает? у меня он должен быть поверх псевдо, а он наоборот

Answer (score 0):

Добавил:

```
.foto-redonda {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```css
block {
  height: 440px;
  width: 270px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px #000000;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding: 40px 10px 0px 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.foto-redonda {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.block::before {
  content: "";
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #016abb;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0px -10px -10px -10px;
}

.foto-redonda {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="foto">
    <img class="foto-redonda" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=Foto" alt="Foto participante">
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <h3>Un señor cualquiera</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc efficitur tellus vel sapien porta, eget bibendum libero viverra. Nullam turpis libero, viverra non lectus et, elementum mattis turpis. Sed laoreet, orci sed dignissim suscipit, orci sem
      ultrices turpis, interdum mollis nunc augue congue purus. Praesent a facilisis enim. Proin ultricies aliquet sem at suscipit. Nam mollis ipsum nec porttitor luctus. Sed non ex vitae odio vehicula efficitur eget at sapien. Curabitur nec pretium mauris.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: мне надо, что-бы сзади фотки было синее полотно, оно сделано. но фото, уходит под псевдо, и не получается, это можно как то решить?

Comment: все, спасибо я не так сначало понял

Comment: @Jrac если ответ решил проблему, поставь галочку. Это поможет в будущем ориентироваться на этот ответ другим страждущим.